# Could someone help to analyse the time complexity of my code?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

**Scenario:**

I'm trying to solve one question on LintCode, "Longest Consecutive Sequence", where given an unsorted array of integers, find the length of the longest consecutive elements sequence.

Link to the original question: https://www.lintcode.com/en/problem/longest-consecutive-sequence/

So here is my intuitive solution:

```
public int longestConsecutive(int[] num) {
    // write you code here
    if (num == null || num.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    HashSet<Integer> hash = new HashSet<Integer>();
    int count = 1, offset = 1, max = 1, loops;

    for (int i : num) {
        hash.add(i);
    }

    for (Object i : hash.toArray()) {
        Integer elem = (Integer)i;

        hash.remove(elem);
        loops = hash.size();

        while (offset <= loops) {
            if (hash.contains(elem + offset)) {
                count++;
                hash.remove(elem + offset);
            } else {
                break;
            }

            offset++;
        }

        offset = 1;

        while (offset <= loops) {
            if (hash.contains(elem - offset)) {
                count++;
                hash.remove(elem - offset);
            } else {
                break;
            }

            offset++;
        }

        max = Math.max(max, count);
        count = 1;
        offset = 1;
    }

    return max;
}
```

**Explanation:**

I'm trying to loop through every element in the `HashSet`.

For each element, first check its incremental consecutive neighbours by as far as the size of the HashSet after removing itself ( because best case all remaining elements in the HashSet are its consecutive neighbours).

For every valid neighbour, we increase the count and remove the neighbour from the HashSet. If we hit a miss, then we break and start to check its decremental neighbours in the same manner.

Repeat until the HashSet is empty and return the max length.

**Question:**

1. What is the time complexity of this code?
2. Would it be correct to say that the number of inner loop iterations in each outer loop iteration depends on the number of inner loop iterations in the previous outer loop iteration?

My thought is that although there are while loops within the for loop, the number of iterations for those loop are dependent. For example, if all elements in the input are consecutive, then the outer for loop will only execute once, since all operations are done by the two inner while loops. After both while loops are exit, there will be no elements in the HashSet.

On the other hand, if no element is consecutive, all operations are done by the outer for loop.

3. Do we consider the cost of `hash.toArray()` as well?
4. Finally, is there a way to combine the two inner while loop together?

Does Java support something like "dynamic for loop", by which I mean the number of iterations can change while the for loop is executing? I'm asking this as I cannot get around the `ConcurrentModificationException` when using a `for (Object i: hash)` while removing the elements via `hash.remove` in the inner loops. So I used `for (Object i : hash.toArray())` as as work-around, therefore adding an unwanted overhead.

Comment: Time complexity describes the *worst case scenario runtime*. Go through your code, and think about worst case scenarios. Is it possible every element *may* be processed? Then it would be O(n), or worse.

Comment: I would delete any line of code that is not a loop. This should help you look at the complexity

Comment: every single instruction is 1, every loop is n, every loop in loop is n*n, every loop in loop in loop is n*n*n and so on. So you have complexity O(n) = n+2n^2 (first loop n and 2*n^2 for the two loops in one loop). But in time complexity you usually take only the3 part with biggest degree, in your case it is n^2, so you can say, that the complexity of this code is O(n^2)

Comment: Some things to note is you're looking for sequential objects in a `HashSet`, which does not guarantee consistant ordering. A `LinkedHashSet` or `List` (or, for pre-sorted, a `TreeSet`) would be more appropriate here. Additionally you are modifying the underlying collection while iterating it, which will throw a CME. Lastly, with time complexity you don't only have to think about loops (like other posters mentioned), you need to additionally think about the complexity of the operations you call (e.g. collection operations like `#contains`).

Comment: @Rogue, sorry what do you mean by "looking for sequential objects in a HashSet"? I'm relatively new to Java, please elaborate. My while loops are looking for consecutive neighbours, but I don't think the order of elements matters since I'm using hash.contains() method anyway. But I do agree I should have considered the cost for collection methods like #contains(). I just consider it to be O(1) cuz I'm using a HashSet.

Comment: A `TreeSet` will sort the collection beforehand, meaning you can iterate the collection one time (`O(n)`) and not have to do random retrievals which may or may not work (you would just check if the leap between the current and previous number was `> 1`). The reason I suggested ordering is because you're looking for relational data (data which its influence is determined by other data), so sorting it and operating off of that is faster than attempting to retrieve data which may or may not be there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author doesn't understand what He is aking, and is changing His mind on the fly, which renders the question impossible to answer. Should be closed.

Comment: @bashnesnos You rage-donwvoted me because I answered previous version of the question, and You wanted to have your answer upper on the page - that was your only reason.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki not exactly, I downvoted your answer because it is misleading (the same as the other answer) and is incorrect in regards to the time complexity of the author's code. I did it only after I didn't recieve any explanation from you. If you explain your answer/correct it as per my questions I'll reclaim my vote back, or upvote if I'm wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per your questions:

> What is the time complexity of this code?

Your code complexity is already O(N) in worst case.

`for (int i : num) {` - a loop of `N` elements.
`hash.toArray()` - another loop of `N` elements in worst case (i.e. no duplicates)
`while (offset <= loops) {` - either of these loops is `N` elements in worst case. Since you reduce size of the `hash` each time a match is found and you break the loop if no matching element is found - this worst case would happen only once, and only for one of the loops (either `hash.remove(elem - offset)` or `hash.remove(elem + offset)`). So it won't be more than `N` elements for these 2 loops altogether.

In total you would get O(3 x N), but since constants could be omitted in worst-case analysis your alghorithm is O(N).

> Is my thought correct?

Yes, your thought is correct.

> Finally, is there a way to combine the two inner while loop together?

There is no point in 2 loops actually, since eventually you'll go over all the elements. But you need to map your sequences to your elements somehow in order to keep the track where the sequence starts and where it ends.
In you case you are keeping the sequence start and end in the loop body - which means you have to look left and right in order not to miss any candidates. If you would transform your numbers into actual sequences with a start and length, and them just try to combine them - you would need to traverse only one direction (either `elem + offset` or `elem - offset`). You can have a look at `elem + offset` implemetation in `longestConsecutiveN`

**Theory meets the practice**

In reply to `add sorting` suggestions: adding any sorting (either via a tree or `Array.sort`) would make it O(N x logN), since even the best sorting alghorithms like `timsort` have time-complexity O(N x logN).

Though *practically*, a *theoretical* O(N x logN) alghorithm could run faster than a O(N) alghorithm due to usually ommited factors (operations considered O(1)).
It's a little bit out of scope but still interesting to share in current context.

Here you are couple of implementations to combine:

- `longestConsecutiveBefore` - the original code - `time-complexity O(3 x N)`
- `longestConsecutiveAfter` - slightly improved original, mainly removing extra `hash.toArray` and some unnecessary `HashSet` accesses - `time-complexity O(2 x N)`
- `longestConsecutiveN` - a different approach, which attempts to reduce the array of elements to a `HashMap` of sequences and then combining those - `time-complexity O(2 x N)`
- `longestConsecutiveTree` - a `TreeSet` approach, sorting the array first and then checking sequences in one go - `time-complexity O(N x logN + N)`
- `longestConsecutiveSorted` - an `Array.sort` approach, sorting the array first and then checking sequences in one go - `time-complexity O(N x logN + N)`

Here is all the code (except the original `longestConsecutiveBefore` - it's in the question):

```
public int longestConsecutiveAfter(int[] num) {
    // write you code here
    if (num == null || num.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }



    HashSet<Integer> hash = new HashSet<Integer>();
    int count = 1, currentSequence = 1;

    for (Integer i : num) {
        hash.add(i);
    }

    if (hash.size() == 1) return 1; //all elements are the same

    int i = 0;
    while (hash.size() > 0) {
        int elem = num[i++];
        if (hash.remove(elem)) {
            int lcursor = elem;
            int rcursor = elem;
            currentSequence = 1;

            while (hash.remove(++rcursor)) {
                currentSequence++;
            }

            while (hash.remove(--lcursor)) {
                currentSequence++;
            }

            count = Math.max(count, currentSequence);
        }
    }

    return count;
}

public static int longestConsecutiveN(int[] num) {
    // write you code here
    if (num == null || num.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> hash = new HashMap<>();
    for (Integer i : num) {
        hash.put(i, 1);
    }

    Integer max = 1;
    Integer curSeqLength = null;
    for (Integer i: num) {
        if ((curSeqLength = hash.get(i)) != null) {
            Integer mergeSeqLength = null;
            while ((mergeSeqLength = hash.remove(i + curSeqLength)) != null) {
                curSeqLength = curSeqLength + mergeSeqLength;
                hash.put(i, curSeqLength);
            }
            if (curSeqLength > max) max = curSeqLength;
        }
    }

    return max;
}

public int longestConsecutiveTree(int[] num) {
    // write you code here
    if (num == null || num.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    Set<Integer> hash = new TreeSet<>();
    int count = 1, currentSequence = 1;

    for (int i : num) {
        hash.add(i);
    }

    if (hash.size() == 1) return 1; //all elements are the same

    Iterator<Integer> iterator = hash.iterator();
    int elem = iterator.next();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        int cursor = iterator.next();
        if (cursor - elem == 1) {
            currentSequence++;
        } else {
            count = Math.max(count, currentSequence);
            currentSequence = 1;
        }
        elem = cursor;
    }

    count = Math.max(count, currentSequence);
    return count;
}



public int longestConsecutiveSorted(int[] num) {
    // write you code here
    if (num == null || num.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (num.length == 1) {
        return 1;
    }


    int count = 1, currentSequence = 1;

    int[] copy = new int[num.length];
    System.arraycopy(num, 0, copy, 0, num.length);
    Arrays.sort(copy);
    int i = 1;
    while (++i < copy.length) {
        int diff = copy[i] - copy[i - 1];
        if (diff == 1) {
            currentSequence++;
        } else if (diff != 0) {
            count = Math.max(count, currentSequence);
            currentSequence = 1;
        }
    }

    count = Math.max(count, currentSequence);
    return count;
}
```

Heres are the benchmark results ([source available via a gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d01037fb62604a11a39851e46581de6e)):

```
100 elements
Benchmark                         Mode      Cnt     Score    Error   Units
LongestConsecutiveBench.sorted  sample  4851102  1600,768 ±  78,974  ns/op
LongestConsecutiveBench.n       sample  6464973  4008,925 ± 13,191   ns/op
LongestConsecutiveBench.after   sample  5847310  4452,501 ± 15,122   ns/op
LongestConsecutiveBench.tree    sample  5934834  4489,135 ± 72,672   ns/op
LongestConsecutiveBench.before  sample  4684143  5704,490 ± 88,950   ns/op


1000 elements
Benchmark                         Mode      Cnt      Score     Error   Units
LongestConsecutiveBench.sorted  sample  6629830   2002,731 ± 28,507    ns/op
LongestConsecutiveBench.after   sample  3379354  52919,011 ± 54,184    ns/op
LongestConsecutiveBench.n       sample  3415801  56399,068 ± 53,115    ns/op
LongestConsecutiveBench.before  sample  2717184  73837,520 ± 192,104   ns/op
LongestConsecutiveBench.tree    sample  1360498  147322,523 ± 565,219  ns/op

10000 elements
Benchmark                         Mode     Cnt        Score      Error   Units
LongestConsecutiveBench.sorted  sample  5319312   18974,711 ± 84,455     ns/op
LongestConsecutiveBench.after   sample  233353   859290,201 ± 1229,219   ns/op
LongestConsecutiveBench.n       sample  210452   952588,627 ± 1328,927   ns/op
LongestConsecutiveBench.before  sample  161523  1241214,958 ± 5034,863   ns/op
LongestConsecutiveBench.tree    sample   78707  2552443,734 ± 10685,110  ns/op
```

So the *theoretically* slower `LongestConsecutiveBench.sorted` O(N x logN + N) implementation is *practically* better than other O(N). This is happening, because we are operating upon a primitives and would have to do a lot of auto-boxing (int -> Integer and vice-versa). A primitive-typed `HashMap` would solve the problem.

It's worth to mention, that in the same circumstances the *theoretically* slower `LongestConsecutiveBench.tree` O(N x logN + N) implementation is slower *practically* then other O(N) implementations as it should be.

Answer (score -1):

The Time complexity is worst case complexity.
So it looks like O(n^2), with n= num of elements in the set.

In fact:

```
     for (Object i : hash.toArray()) {
```

is O(n) supposing, easily, that `hash.toArray()` is performed only once (otherwise it will add another O(n) loop).

Then

```
     while (offset <= loops) {
```

is also O(n) as loops = hash.size()

So, because the loops are one inside the other, the Time complexity is O(n^2).

NB the second

```
    while (offset <= loops) {
```

does not influence the overall complexity, as O(n+n)= O(n). Then O(n*(n+n))=O(n^2).

However, you manipulate the hashset, but not the array in which you iterate in the outer loop. So that array is never made empty and you iterate over it in any case.

Finally i'm not sure your algorithm solves completely the problem.  What happens if you've a set with all elements in sequence, but not ordered and the first element from the outer loop is in the middle of the sequence ? I believe you'll find 2 sequences with half of the elements in the set, but not the longest sequence which is the whole set.

Comment: It's not an n^2 for the inner loops since even in the worst-case of all-unique-no-sequnces the break condition would stop both loops after just 1 iteration.